# Combining 2 promises in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im combining 2 promises but isnt working, in a service i have 2 methods, where the method "UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()" gets the current user information and than there is a "UserService.getAccountTypeData(idUser)", where gets the usertype information, but to get to the second method i need the userID, so basically first i call the "UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()", get the id, and than call "UserService.getAccountTypeData(idUser)", but isnt working.

```
 function isAccount(accountName) {
             UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(function (response) {
                    var userDetails = response.data;

                });


            UserService.getAccountTypeData(idUser)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var userDetails = response.data;
                    return  userDetails;
                });

}
```

PS: I already injected the service...

Answer (score 2):

You can chain your promises by returning values from your `.then()` functions.

```
function isAccount(accountName) {
    return UserService.getAuthenticatedUser(accountName) // pass in accountName argument?
        .then(function(response) {
            var userDetails = response.data;
            return userDetails.Id; // user id value
        })
        .then(UserService.getAccountTypeData) // userDetails.Id gets passed to getAccounttypeData method
        .then(function(response) {
            var userDetails = response.data;
            return userDetails;
        });

}

// usage
isAccount('AccountA').then(function(userDetails) {
    // do something with userDetails
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steam, just one question, is it correct nesting like this? `code` UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(function (response) {
                    var userDetails = response.data;

                     UserService.getAccountTypeData(idUser)
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var userDetails = response.data;
                      return  userDetails;
                  });

                });`code`

Comment: @MarcoPereira nesting will work as well, just make sure you're referencing defined variables. In your commented example, `idUser` does not exist. I'm assuming that would come from your first `userDetails` instance.

Comment: @MarcoPereira you haven't defined `idUser` but otherwise would be basiclly the same

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with asynchronous calls, so when you call the `.then()` method, it's executing the function and wiring up the callback to an anonymous function passed as a parameter to `then()`.  If the second is dependent on the first, you could nest them like this...

```
function isAccount(accountName) {
      UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
         .then(function (response) {
             var userDetails = response.data;
             UserService.getAccountTypeData(idUser)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var userDetails = response.data;
                    return  userDetails;
                });
         });
}
```

Comment: missing a return in first `then()`

Comment: You know... I was thinking about the return, and with these calls executing asynchronously, I don't think he can return it the way he's trying to here.  I think the returns are useless.

Comment: sure you can, you need to return `UserService.getAccountTypeData()` promise and you also need to return to `isAccount()` the same way it's done in other answer

Comment: But once `UserService.getAuthenticatedUser().then(...)` has called, it's already exited `isAccount(...)`, correct?.  It will execute the anon function when the service call is completed, but that's in its own closure.

Comment: No... you are creating a promise chain. So `isAccount()` would be called as `isAccount().then(...` but you need promise returned to that next `then()`

Comment: I see what your intentions are now - you're saying you should turn isAccount into a promise call.  I misinterpreted what you said.

Comment: Need to evaluate or use the results somewhere so since nothing shown in question would have to assume that is intention